# Is it possible to link scripts in python?

Tags: python

Is it possible to make a main script in python, where i link all the other scripts?
e.g. Make a x script and y script and link them in the main script, so when I run the main script the code will successfully run.

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way if the code of main file is inside a function.

Suppose the main script (`file1.py`):

```
def main():
  return "Hello world!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(main())
```

Then inside the second script you can import and call function like:

```
import file1
print(file1.main())
```

Let's go further.

Here we have a class inside the main script:

```
class myClass:
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = 10
    def getHello(self):
      return "Hello world!"
```

Now we can use the class from the main script like:

```
import file1
theClass = file1.myClass()
print(theClass.x)
print(theClass.getHello())
```

Answer (score 0):

To get variables, functions, classes *etc.* of y script on x script, add this line to the beginning of the x script:

```py
import [name of y script]
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE: both scripts should be in the SAME directory**

Hope it work